# JSF passing a list to be displayed in another page

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

Hi i am new to JSF an i am a bit lost. This what i want to do.
I have a page where i display  a list of shows where every show has a list of representations. I want the user by clicking on a particular show to go a page where only the linked representations to the show are displayed. Here are my current .xhtml pages and my two managed beans. What they do right now is that they display all shows and all lists.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SHOW_SPECTACLE")
public class Spectacle implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "T_TYPES_SPECTACLE")
    @Column(name = "TYPES_SPECTACLE")
    private List<String> typesSpectacle;

    @Column(name = "NOM_SPECTACLE")
    private String nomSpectacle;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "LIEN_VIDEO")
    private String lienVideo; // type Blop
    @Column(name = "LIEN_IMAGE")
    private String lienImage;

    @OneToOne
    private Artiste artiste;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "spectacle")
    private List<Representation> representations;

}

public class Representation implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "NB_BILLETS_DISPO")
    private Integer nbBilletsDispo;
    @Column(name = "PRIX")
    private Float prix;
    @Column(name = "NOM")
    private String nom;
    @Column(name = "ADRESSE")
    private String adresse;
    @Column(name = "DATE_DEBUT")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateDebut;
    @Column(name = "DATE_FIN")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateFin;
    @Column(name = "IS_ANNULATION")
    private Boolean isAnnulation;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "representation")
    private Salle salle;

    @ManyToOne
    private Spectacle spectacle;

}
```

The xhtml page sections that display all the the shows, i use in it some primefaces components

```
<h:form id="form">  

        <p:dataGrid var="spec" value="#{menuCtrl.spectacles}" columns="3"  
                    rows="12" paginator="true"  
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="9,12,15">  

            <p:panel header="#{spec.nomSpectacle}" style="text-align:center">

                <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%"> 
                    <ui:param name="imgPath" value="images:#{spec.artiste.lienPhoto}.png" />
                    <p:graphicImage value="#{resource[imgPath]}" />  

                    <h:outputText value="#{spec.description}" />  

<!--                        <p:commandLink update=":form:carDetail" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" title="View Detail">  
                            <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search" style="margin:0 auto;" />   
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="{spec}"   
                                                         target="{tableBean.selectedCar}" />  
                    </p:commandLink>  -->
                </h:panelGrid>  
            </p:panel>  

        </p:dataGrid> 
    </h:form>
```

edit here is the bean used

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "menuCtrl")
@ApplicationScoped
public class MenuControleur extends AbstractControleur implements Serializable {
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationControleur.class);

// cache
private List<Spectacle> spectacles;
private List<Representation> representations;
private List<Artiste> artistes;


private List<Representation> representationsFiltrees;


@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // instanciation couche [métier]
    super.initStubsPresentation();

    this.spectacles = this.stubsDaoPresentation.getAllSpectacle();
    this.representations = this.stubsDaoPresentation.getAllRepresentation();
    this.artistes = this.stubsDaoPresentation.getAllArtistes(); 

    log.info("sonar source Spectacle 1: " + this.spectacles);
    log.info("sonar source Representation 1: " + this.representations);
    log.info("sonar source Artiste 1: " + this.artistes);
}    

public List<Representation> getRepresentationsFiltrees() {
    return representationsFiltrees;
}

public void setRepresentationsFiltrees(List<Representation> representationsFiltrees) {
    this.representationsFiltrees = representationsFiltrees;
}



public String doHomme(){
    return "eticket.index";
}

public String doCart(){
    return "eticket.pageCart";
}

public String doShow(){
    return "eticket.pageShows";
}

/**
 * Creates a new instance of MenuControleur
 */
public MenuControleur() {  }

public List<Spectacle> getSpectacles() {
    return spectacles;
}

public void setSpectacles(List<Spectacle> spectacles) {
    this.spectacles = spectacles;
}

public List<Representation> getRepresentations() {
    return representations;
}

public void setRepresentations(List<Representation> representations) {
    this.representations = representations;
}

public List<Artiste> getArtistes() {
    return artistes;
}

public void setArtistes(List<Artiste> artistes) {
    this.artistes = artistes;
}
```

}

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this link](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html) or at [this one](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html) if you're using JSF2. Also, watch out, what you currently show is not the code of your managed beans, but the code of your entities instead.

Comment: But that Doesn't answer how you o from one page to another.

Comment: The xhtml that you have given doesn't match with the functionality you want to achieve.

Comment: @user2133558 That defines a set of different mechanisms to communicate in a JSF application, so you can chose the one you prefer. If you're not asking about how can you pass data from one page to another one, then I suggest you update your answer to trully reflect what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: hi i updated it and added the managed bean. Well i wanna know how for example by clicking on a link you go to page that will take a certain list as a paramter to build it self. From what i have seen, each page only communicate with a bean. let's say that i include a method in the managed bean that will extract the list of each show, how can i use that list in another page ?

Comment: Can someone give me a link to a REAL app example and the helloWorld thing ?

Comment: You can use `@ViewScoped` beans to manage the pages. You can pass the list from one to the other using flash scope. There you have a [minimal example](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/07/learning-jsf2-using-flash-scope/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add  a

```
`<h:link value="Second Page" outcome="secondpage" >
    <f:param name="id" value="#{bean.id}" />
</h:link>
```

`

or `<a href="secondpage.jsf?id=#{bean.id}">Second Page</a>` in your first page

You need something like this in the bean for your second page

```
@ManagedBean("bean2")
public class SecondPageBean {

  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")
  private String id;
  private String name;

  @PostConstruct    
  public String init() {
     // initialieMySecondPageBasedOnIdFromFirstPage(id);
  }
}
```

You can also do this in your secondpage xhtml to replace `@ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")`,

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}" />
</f:metadata>
```

However if you want to share the object/state between the two consecutive requests then have a look into Flash scope.

[Understand Flash Scope in JSF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194112/understand-flash-scope-in-jsf2)

Comment: Hi avinash, thanks for the reply. I will lookup to your example, but i have tried to simulate the example give by @Xtrem-Biker, this is what i am trying to do.
i will put a command button that will invoke a new method in MenuControlleur, that method will have to put spec.representations in a new list attribute in and redirect the user to the rep pages. the redirection is working but not passing the list.

Comment: RequestScope beans will not persist between redirects , but as I see in your example , you are using a applicationscoped bean so you should be able to get and store the value from that bean on any page.