# JSF 2.2.4 and Flash com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash getCurrentFlashManager

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, flash-scope

I'm facing this bug.

```
5 déc. 2013 13:15:15 com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash getCurrentFlashManager
GRAVE: JSF1094: Could not decode flash data from incoming cookie value Invalid characters in decrypted value.  Processing will continue, but the flash is unavailable for this request.
```

I already read this.

[Previous Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668986/exception-about-flash-in-mojarra-jsf)

It should be corrected on this version, or i missing something ?

What is the problem exactly ? What could i do to solve it ? (only wait for another version ?)

Thanks for help.

Comment: It looks to be a bug. I have the same issue. :( and didn't find information how to fix it. SEVERE: JSF1094: Could not decode flash data from incoming cookie value Invalid characters in decrypted value.  Processing will continue, but the flash is unavailable for this request.

Comment: Try to change to JSF 2.2.5 , and don't use uppercase,é,à,é characters in your flashed input, config your database utf8_general_ci if you first retrieved the parameters from them. Yeah it's no clear why, but some of this change make my error goes away :).Maybe it is just because of the update of my 2.2.4 to 2.2.5.I'am Still stuck with the  JSF1095 but no more JSF1094. Go luck.

Comment: Thank you!! Changing the version from 2.2.4 to 2.2.5 resolves the JSF1094 issue. That's all in my case. Thank you again! :)