# How pass hidden params when redirect to another page

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I redirect to details page with:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("detailsTask?id=" + process.getId());
```

And the bean configuration is:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>detailsTaskBacking</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>pt.ano.gspgsemdd.webapp.tasks.DetailsTaskBacking</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>id</property-name>
        <value>#{param.id}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

In this way the link is visible and the ID too. I need pass this ID hidden. Any idea?

Comment: Use the flash scope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194112/understand-flash-scope-in-jsf2/21277621#21277621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the flash scope: [stackoverflow.com/questions/11194112/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194112/understand-flash-scope-in-jsf2)