# Pass parameters from bean to navigated view

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, navigation, parameter-passing

What I do now:

call an action method

```
            <p:commandButton value="Fine"  
                             action="#{dtIndexBean.forwardAction}"  
                             styleClass="ui-priority-primary" 
                             ajax="false">  
                    <f:param name="result" value="fine"/>  
            </p:commandButton>
```

in forwardAction method, validate the input and forward to another view if validation goes fine

```
        String result =  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("result");

            if (result.equals("wrong")) {
                System.out.println("WRONG!!");

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, 
                            "", "WRONG!!"));
            return "";

        } else{
            paramBean.putForwardParameter("message", "Hello!");
            return "forwarded.xhtml";
        }
```

I need to pass some parameters to forwarded view, now I put them in a session bean (here its name is "paramBean") so I can read them in the backing bean of the forwarded view:

```
String message;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        message = paramBean.getParameter("message");
        paramBean.clearForwardParameter();
    }
```

I only feel that this is clumsy due to the presence of an additional bean. Is there a less clumsy way to do this?

Comment: you can fine the example at https://www.dropbox.com/s/ia4fa9naeppjka7/Test-Forwarding-portlet.war?dl=0

Comment: Maybe with `return "forwarded.xhtml?message=blabla"` ?

Comment: Is the `forwardParameter` something you need to keep private? Then, the [flash scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194112/understand-flash-scope-in-jsf2) does exactly what you're looking for. If not, you could go with @JaqenH'ghar's answer

Comment: The flash scope is a good solution, cleaner than mine. Unfortunately  "forwarded.xhtml?message=blabla" doesn't work...