# Keep the state of ManagedBean in page change

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, many-to-one, view-scope

I have a entity `Artist` and this artist should have one or many `Music`s.

When user click in "New Artist", can fill all fields for an artist (name, address, style and etc). This form is associated a managed bean called `ArtistMB`. As I said, `Artist` can have one or many `Music`s, so inside this form user should click in "New Music" and be redirected to another page `new_music.xhtml`, but the user has not saved `Artist` in database yet, all content of `ArtistMB` should be saved in memory for now, because when user finishes adding new `Music`, this `Music` will be added to a `Set<Music>` inside `Artist` bean, and after all this the `Artist` bean will be saved in database.

How can I do it? If a use `@ViewScoped`, then the state of `ArtistMB` will be lost when I redirect to another page `new_music.xhtml`.

Comment: I would use the same window, probably by opening a modal window that allows add/update the music for the current artist reference. In that way, you can still use the `@ViewScoped` bean and there won't be need to navigate to a new view.

Comment: I cant use modal. I should put informations about Music in new page

Comment: Then save the artist reference somewhere like session or database, retrieve the same artist in the new page and do the modifications.

Comment: I thought that had another way with annotations

Comment: Easiest solution if you need new page would be `@SessionScoped` and storing there `Artist` object and after edit nulling it.

Comment: I read about @ ConversationScoped but this annotation don't exists in JSF 2, and i'm using Spring not CDI. I think this @ ConversationScoped is my solution beucase i can keep the state of ManagedBean while i desire.

Comment: `@ConversationScoped` belongs to CDI and it's easier to invalidate by just removing the query string parameter.

Comment: I dont think that use SessionScoped is a good solution. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can put your Artist into the Flash before navigating to your musics-page, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11194112/4308751).